# Assigning one variable value to another

Tags: c

I know this is probably going to be very simplistic for most people here but I'm new at this so please don't mind me. I am trying assign on variable value to another by using its name in a printf/scanf line in a c program. Here's the code:

```
int day, month, counter;
int sunday = 0;
int monday = 1;
int tuesday = 2;
int wednesday = 3;
int thursday = 4;
int friday = 5;
int saturday = 6;

printf("Enter how many days in the month:\n");
scanf("%i", &month);

printf("Enter what day the month starts on:\n");
scanf("%i", &day);
```

This is just part of it but what I'm trying to do is make it so that when the user inputs the actual days name in the second printf/scanf line that it will call the int's value and assign it to the days value. Issue is that it isn't working and I don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean by entering the "actual day name". If you are talking abt the user entering "sunday,monday" etc, then why are you storing it in an `int`.

Comment: I think he wants to enter the variable name on the command line and then use the int that's stored in the variable somewhere else.  Sounds to me like he should be using an enum...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in C (enter the name of variable from keyboard when `scanf` is running), this is not a scripting language. Basically, all variable's names are lost during the compile step (they still may be saved as debugging information, which is used by debugger, e.g. gdb, but program usually not uses this at the run time).

You should to input a string (char array with type `char*` or `char []`) via `scanf` with `%s` and then parse it by hand, e.g.

```
char string[50];
scanf("%s", string);
if( strcmp(string, "monday") == 0 )
  day = 1;
else if ( strcmp(string, "tuesday") == 0 )
  day = 2;
```

and so on.

Comment: I guess this answers my question. Like I said I'm new at this so thank you for not bashing me about it =).

Comment: Anyone was in the same situation at some time :)

Comment: He's already using "bash" in sentences...the Force is strong in this one.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, something like that.

```
 int day, month, counter;
 char *dofw[] = { "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", NULL};
 char day_string[20];

 printf("Enter how many days in the month:\n");
 scanf("%d", &month);

 printf("Enter what day the month starts on:\n");
 scanf("%20s", day_string);

 int i;
 day = -1;
 for(i=0; dofw[i]; i++) {
   if(strcmp(day_string, dofw[i]) == 0) {
     day = i;
     break;
   } 
 }
 if(day == -1)
   printf("User Y U not give good day\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a function, or set of functions presenting a single interface to the program using it, that will scan a string (not an integer) already read by the program, and translate that to the appropriate value.  You should probably make the code case-insensitive, and able to accept valid (unique) abbreviations (like Sa, Su, M, Tu, W, Th, F), etc.  You might or might not accept the day-of-week numbers as alternatives to the names.  If you have to worry about internationalization or I18N (S, D, L, J, Ma, Me, V for Samedi, Dimanche, Lundi, Mardi, Mercredi, Jeudi, Vendredi in French, etc) that adds to the complexity of these functions (but not to the complexity of the code using them).

C does not provide a direct way of doing this.  The nearest approach is POSIX [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html), and I don't think it handles this in its fullness.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%d` when you do `scanf()` for `int` types.

[%d and %i are similar but different for scanf().](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Format_placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `scanf` that will accept a signed integer (`%i`) you can't expect nothing more that an integer. If user input a string (say sunday, so you want that day receive '0' value) you have to do it in a different way.

Maybe you can ask to user to insert the format BEFORE entering the data (`printf("Enter the format of day ('n' for name, 'd' for number:\n"`); and then, according to user's choice, you can do a different scan f: if i choosen 'n' then you can go over and find the corrispective numeric value.

If i can suggest you an improvement of your code, you have to declare the different days or with an array or with a struct or enum.

Comment: "'n' for name, 'n' for number" is not likely to get you what you want.